# Propeller from Parallax Inc.(P8X32A-D40) books

Tags: microcontroller

I am keen on microelectronics and micro controllers for robotics and currently using  a  micro controller in a 40-pin DIL package(P8X32A-D40), Propeller from Parallax Inc.
I was wondering if any who also uses this and can recommend some good books on the Propeller and cogs and applications.,

Comment: download the data sheet for the processor. data sheet information is often more complete and reliable. also try app notes and other mfg info

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple:

[Programming and Customizing the Multicore Propeller Microcontroller: The Official Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071664505)

[Programming the Propeller with Spin: A Beginner's Guide to Parallel Processing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071716661)

The first one covers a little bit of the architecture, and then presents several projects to do; the second one concentrates on the Spin language, and how the cogs work.  Both are available in either print form or for the Kindle (which I have).

You can peek inside each of the books on the Amazon page, including the full table of contents to see what they cover.

Answer (score 0):

Not books, but if you're into the Propeller chip, there are a couple of people you should be aware of who are doing really interesting things with Propellers. I became aware of them through their articles in [Circuit Cellar](http://www.circuitcellar.com/) magazine.

The first is [Chris Cantrell](http://www.dtweed.com/circuitcellar/xcantrel.htm). He likes to build (among other things) emulations of retro video games. His website is http://computerarcheology.com/

The second is [Hanno Sander](http://www.dtweed.com/circuitcellar/xsanderh.htm). He does interesting things with robotics and video processing. He also has built some useful Propeller development tools. His website is http://hannoware.com/